# Kernel debugging?

Tags: windows-7, kernel, driver, windbg

I am trying to debug the kernel using windbg.My host is windows 7 x64.My target is windows 7 x86 which is installed in vmware.I have successfully connected to target machine.But  often I am getting an error symbols could not be loaded.I have already set the path for symbols using the url of msdn.But I unable to connect net during debugging.SO I have planned to download symbols and specify the path .If I want to download means whether I have to download the x86 symbols or x64 symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the symbols for the OS that's being debugged, 32-bit Windows 7 in your case.

Comment: I have downloaded windows 7 x86 symbols package and i have installedo.I run the x86 windbg in my host machine

Answer (score 1):

Since your target PC is 32-bit, its drivers will be 32-bit as well and will require the 32-bit symbols for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging session should not matter for connectivity to internet. If that is the issue, you may want to look into that.

You may also want to check:

- Have you saved your workspace settings, so that symbol path is always set appropriately?
- Try `!sym noisy` on debugger prompt and check for which symbols its giving the problems.